# Office 365 API - Create Event With Attachment

Tags: python, office365

I am using the Python script below to create event for Office 365 and it works. However, I have a tough time (googling all day) to find out how can I also include the attachment with the event that is being generated from this script below.

This below code works for creating the event.

```
# Set the request parameters
url = 'https://outlook.office365.com/api/v1.0/me/events?$Select=Start,End'
user = 'user1@domain.com'

pwd = getpass.getpass('Please enter your AD password: ')


# Create JSON payload
data = {
  "Subject": "Testing Outlock Event",
  "Body": {
    "ContentType": "HTML",
    "Content": "Test Content"
  },
  "Start": "2016-05-23T15:00:00.000Z",
  "End": "2016-05-23T16:00:00.000Z",
      "Attendees": [
    {
      "EmailAddress": {
        "Address": "user1@domain.com",
        "Name": "User1"
      },
       "Type": "Required"  },

       {
      "EmailAddress": {
        "Address": "user2@domain.com",
        "Name": "User2"
      },
       "Type": "Optional"  }
  ]
}

json_payload = json.dumps(data)

# Build the HTTP request
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPHandler)
request = urllib2.Request(url, data=json_payload)
auth = base64.encodestring('%s:%s' % (user, pwd)).replace('\n', '')
request.add_header('Authorization', 'Basic %s' % auth)
request.add_header('Content-Type', 'application/json')
request.add_header('Accept', 'application/json')
request.get_method = lambda: 'POST'
# Perform the request
result = opener.open(request)
```

But when I tried to include attachment, it is not working (see below with attachments code)

```
# Set the request parameters
url = 'https://outlook.office365.com/api/v1.0/me/events?$Select=Start,End'
user = 'user1@domain.com'

pwd = getpass.getpass('Please enter your AD password: ')


# Create JSON payload
data = {
  "Subject": "Testing Outlock Event",
  "Body": {
    "ContentType": "HTML",
    "Content": "Test Content"
  },
  "Start": "2016-05-23T15:00:00.000Z",
  "End": "2016-05-23T16:00:00.000Z",
  "Attendees": [
    {
      "EmailAddress": {
        "Address": "user1@domain.com",
        "Name": "User1"
      },
       "Type": "Required"  },

       {
      "EmailAddress": {
        "Address": "user2@domain.com",
        "Name": "User2"
      },
       "Type": "Optional"  }
    ],
  "Attachments": [
          {
            "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.OutlookServices.FileAttachment",
            "Name": "menu.txt",
            "ContentBytes": "JVBERi0xLjMNCjEgMCBvYPRg=="
          }
        ],
   "HasAttachments":"true"
}

json_payload = json.dumps(data)

# Build the HTTP request
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPHandler)
request = urllib2.Request(url, data=json_payload)
auth = base64.encodestring('%s:%s' % (user, pwd)).replace('\n', '')
request.add_header('Authorization', 'Basic %s' % auth)
request.add_header('Content-Type', 'application/json')
request.add_header('Accept', 'application/json')
request.get_method = lambda: 'POST'
# Perform the request
result = opener.open(request)
```

Next, I tried to separate the process.  So, first I created the event and captured the eventID.  Then tried to include the eventID in the URL (see below), but still no luck.

```
import urllib2
import getpass
import os
import json
import sys
import base64
import traceback

# Set the request parameters
url = 'https://outlook.office.com/api/v1.0/me/events/AAMkADA1OWVjOTkxLTlmYmEtNDAwMS04YWU3LTNkNDE2YjU2OGI1ZABGBBBBBBD_fa49_h8OTJ5eGdjSTEF3BwBOcCSV9aNzSoXurwI4R0IgBBBBBBENAABOcCSV9aNzSoXurwI4R0IgAAHzfZ0mAAA=/attachments'
user = 'user1@domain.com'
pwd = "password123"

# Create JSON payload
data = {
        "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.OutlookServices.FileAttachment",
        "Name": "menu.txt",
        "ContentBytes": "VGVzdCAxMjM0NQ=="
      }


print data

json_payload = json.dumps(data)

# Build the HTTP request
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPHandler)
request = urllib2.Request(url, data=json_payload)
auth = base64.encodestring('%s:%s' % (user, pwd)).replace('\n', '')
request.add_header('Authorization', 'Basic %s' % auth)
request.add_header('Content-Type', 'application/json')
request.add_header('Accept', 'application/json')
request.get_method = lambda: 'POST'
# Perform the request
result = opener.open(request).read()
```

Any helps would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create attachment for the event, we need send another request. Here is the description for [creating the attachment](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/calendar-rest-operations#create-attachments) for the exist event.

[image]

After we create the attachments, we also need to update the event so that others can see the changes.

Here is an example that create the attachment for the event:

**Create an event**:

```
POST: https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/events
authorization: bearer {token}
content-type: application/json
{
 "Subject": "Discuss the Calendar REST API",
  "Body": {
    "ContentType": "HTML",
    "Content": "I think it will meet our requirements!"
  },
  "Start": {
      "DateTime": "2016-08-15T14:00:00",
      "TimeZone": "Pacific Standard Time"
  },
  "End": {
      "DateTime": "2016-08-15T14:30:00",
      "TimeZone": "Pacific Standard Time"
  },
  "Attendees": [
    {
      "EmailAddress": {
        "Address": "nanyu@o365e3w15.onmicrosoft.com",
        "Name": "Nan Yu"
      },
      "Type": "Required"
    }
  ]
}
```

**Add attachment**

```
POST: https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/events/{eventId}/attachments
authorization: bearer {token}
content-type: application/json
{
"@odata.type":"#Microsoft.OutlookServices.FileAttachment",
"Name":"test.txt",
"ContentBytes":"aHR0cDovL2dpb25rdW56LmdpdGh1Yi5pby9jaGFydGlzdC1qcy9leGFtcGxlcy5odG1sDQoNCmh0dHBzOi8vd3d3LnlvdXR1YmUuY29tL3dhdGNoP3Y9MGttZGpxZ085SVkNCjM2OjAyDQpodHRwczovL3d3dy55b3V0dWJlLmNvbS93YXRjaD92PW9FVHY2djlmN3djIA0KNjoxOQ0KDQpodHRwczovL2FuZ3VsYXItdWkuZ2l0aHViLmlvL2Jvb3RzdHJhcC8="
}
```

The content bytes are the base64 format string of the text file and here is an sample that convert the text file to base64 string using C#:

```
Convert.ToBase64String(File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\users\user1\desktop\test.txt"))
```

**Update the event**

```
PATCH:https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/events/{eventid}
authorization: bearer {token}
content-type: application/json
{
"Body": {
    "ContentType": "HTML",
    "Content": "I think it will meet our requirements!(Update attachments)"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for responding.  So in my script, I need to create attachment first, then create the event, then capture the event_id, and then update that event with the attachment created?  Sorry, I am lost, please help with some sample code....  appreciated.

Comment: Since I am not familiar with PHP, I would provide a raw REST sample in the orignal post for your reference. Hope it is helpful.

Comment: Thank you for being very helpful. I am using Python and also new to Python. I was able to create the event, capture the eventID, but I am totally stuck at how to convert file to base64 format to add attachment.  Any advice? Also, Can I attach different file extensions like pdf, doc, jpeg, and excel?

Comment: I updated my posted with attachment code that I tried, but no luck. Please take a look to see what I am doing wrong.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: The endpoint "https://outlook.office.com" is not support the basic token. Did it work for you if you replace it with "https://outlook.office365.com"? To call the Office 365 REST API, we need to use **bearer** token which we need to register the app and using the **OAuth**  to request the token.  You can refer [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-protocols-oauth-code/) for more detail. And this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/howto/common-app-authentication-tasks) is helpful to understand authentication with Office 365 APIs.

Comment: I replaced the endpoint to outlook.office365.co‌​‌​‌​m and it seems to work. I see the attachment in the event of the meeting organizer, but I don't see that attachment in the meeting event of the attendees.  So, I did a PATCH to update that event, and all attendees see the attachment.  Is there a way that I can create event but DON'T send it, add attachment to that event using eventID just created, and then send the event to all attendees at once time? Rather than send an event, and then send an update with attachment (2 notification messages).  I am really appreciated your help on this.

Comment: Yes, after you patch the event the others would see the attachments also. And it is not support that create an event without send the notification at present. If you require this feature you may submit the feedback from [here](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/)

Comment: Hi Fei Xue, I think you helped this person who had same problem like mine [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/223b2e54-4b3f-4f3d-822a-534c93b18b1f/outlook-calendar-office-365-rest-api-creating-meeting-with-attachment-in-it?forum=appsforoffice).  Do you know how he was able to create event with attachment at the same time?

Comment: @Milacay Yes. We are able to add the attachments while we using the Mail REST api. But based on the test, it is not working for the event REST at present.